# Automate truncate/copy of table data

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Every week, I have to run a script that truncates a bunch of tables. Then I use the export data task to move the data to another server (same database name).

The servers aren't linked, I can't save the export job, and my permissions/settings are limited by the DBA (I am an admin on the databases). I have windows authentication on both servers only. The servers are different versions (2005/2008).

My question is is there a way to automate this with my limited ability to modify the servers? Perhaps using Powershell?

Selecting all these tables and stuff in the export wizard week after week is a pain.

Comment: This should be happening through SSIS. Create the package, schedule it to run weekly as a job, and you're finished. Doing it manually is wasting a ton of time, and introducing a huge chance for errors.

Comment: I don't have access to SSIS and can't get it.

Comment: My point is, this is one of the things SSIS was made for - as you describe it, it sounds like a pretty basic ETL. To ignore that entirely and instead depend upon a manual process is a major risk on the part of your DBA(s) and management. **Someone** needs to make a decision that things need to be done in a better way.

Comment: Maybe you've never worked in a corporate environment. They just don't give access of anything to everybody.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you personally will be doing everything in every database. What I am suggesting is that you go to the people who can make decisions (the DBA, your manager, etc.) and say "hey, the way we're doing this right now is pretty klunky and it'd be really easy for something to get botched and that will cost the company X dollars/hours. Why can't we use a more appropriate tool for the job, like SSIS?"

Comment: BTW, I think the wizard you're using **already uses** SSIS behind the scenes. Try [saving the package](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186943.aspx) for re-use later - which means you should be able to schedule it too.

Comment: It errors out when I try to save it. I realize SSIS is the ideal solution. I am looking for something quick and dirty that doesn't involve the infrastructure team, DBAs, etc. and a whole production.  This will only continue for 3 more months and people don't want to bother.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DBATOOLS:

```
$splat = @{
  SqlInstance         = '{source instance}'
  Database            = 'tempdb'
  Destination         = '{dest instance}'
  DestinationDatabase = 'tempdb'
  Table               = 'table1' # you can provide a list of tables
  AutoCreateTable     = $true
  Truncate            = $true
}
Copy-DbaDbTableData @splat
```

If you don't have dbatools: https://dbatools.io/getting-started/

Comment: Why -1 when I provided exactly what was asked for:"Perhaps using Powershell"? At the very least, leave a comment that can help provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the SQL Server Management console apps, try something this from a different system.

```
C:\> bcp ExportImportFile.inp out prod.dbo.[Table] -b 10000 -S %SQLSERVER% -U %USERNAME% -P %PASSWORD% -T -c > C:\Temp\ExportImport.log

C:\> sqlcmd -S %SQLSERVER% -U %USERNAEM% -P %PASSWORD% -Q "Use Prod;TRUNCATE TABLE [Table];" >> C:\Temp\ExportImport.log

C:\> bcp prod.dbo.[Table] in ExportImportFile.inp -b 10000 -S %SQLSERVER% -U %USERNAME% -P %PASSWORD% -T -c >> C:\Temp\ExportImport.log
```